# ufw hostname resolution

Tags: ssh, ufw, hostname

I enabled ssh logging on a remote machine. Then I configured ufw for ssh (22), DHCP (67,68) and DNS (53)

I can logging by ip address and hostname when ufw is disabled:

```
$ ssh user@192.168.0.240 # OK
$ ssh user@pc1 # OK
$ arp -a
pc1 (192.168.0.240)
```

When I enable ufw, I can only connect by ip address, hostname resolution is failing:

```
$ ssh user@192.168.0.240 # OK
$ user@pc1 # NOK
Could not resolve hostname pc1:  Name or service not known
$ arp -a
? (192.168.0.240)
```

So my question is simple: how can I resolve hostnames with ufw enabled ?

**EDIT**: current ufw configuration

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 3142/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 3] 53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 4] 53                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 67/udp                     ALLOW IN    68/udp
[ 6] 68/udp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 7] 3142/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[ 8] 53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[ 9] 53 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[10] 67/udp (v6)                ALLOW IN    68/udp (v6)
[11] 68/udp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: What exactly is your UFW configuration - in particular for DNS?

Comment: ufw allow out 53

Comment: Is the address of `pc1` actually provided by DNS, or is it a local hostname whose lookup relies on avahi / bonjour mDNS? If the latter, you may need to allow multicast to port 5353 as well IIRC

Comment: It's the 2nd case (avahi/mDNS): I allowed 5353 (both direction, tcp/udp) after your comment, but there is no improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
```

helped while issuing the `ssh user@hostname` command: it showed a blocked connection on port 5355, which corresponds to hostmon in `/etc/services`, so

```
$ sudo ufw allow in 5355
```

solved the problem ...